# fetch src value from the string

Tags: javascript, regex

correct regex to fetch src value from  the string.

```js
 var str = "&lt;iframe width=\&quot;1000\&quot; height=\&quot;460\&quot; src=\&quot;https&#58;//myvideo.dpdhl.com/video/CuEt8XJ8uVEU3MZrrjQp5z\&quot; title=\&quot;Test Video for New Component\&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
    
 var re = /^src/g;
 var n = str.match(re);
 console.log(n);
```

//output
&quot;https://myvideo.dpdhl.com/video/CuEt8XJ8uVEU3MZrrjQp5z&quot; title=&quot;Test Video for New Component&quot;></iframe>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using `match` with the regex pattern `\bsrc=\S+`:

```js
var str = "&lt;iframe width=\&quot;1000\&quot; height=\&quot;460\&quot; src=\&quot;https&#58;//myvideo.dpdhl.com/video/CuEt8XJ8uVEU3MZrrjQp5z\&quot; title=\&quot;Test Video for New Component\&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
var src = str.match(/\bsrc=\S+/);
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your input will always look like this or similar, you can also just use `replace`:

```js
const str = "&lt;iframe width=\&quot;1000\&quot; height=\&quot;460\&quot; src=\&quot;https&#58;//myvideo.dpdhl.com/video/CuEt8XJ8uVEU3MZrrjQp5z\&quot; title=\&quot;Test Video for New Component\&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";

const src = str.replace(/^.*?src=\&quot;(.*?)\&quot;.*?$/, "$1");

console.log(src);
```